# How to Sign my Blackberry App using LWUIT 1.5 GUIBuilder

Tags: lwuit, gui-builder

Please can anyone tell me the procedure on how to sign my app for blackberry and get the cod files after i finish a App using blackberry theme in lwuit 1.5 guibuilder .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get certificate from RIM [here](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/).

If you use [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) just get the proper sig files and set them in the plugin. In LWUIT you will need to use the [blackberry signing tool](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/signingauthority.jsp).